# Measure execution time of docker container

Tags: docker, time, docker-container

I have a docker image called `my_image` which launch a command and closes.

When running the image in a container using command `docker run --rm my_image`, is it possible to measure the execution time of the container ?

**Edit :**

I need to see those timing information after container execution, thus I can't use `time` command.

I somehow hoped to find some container execution history kept by docker even if `--rm` was used. But if it doesn't exist, then @tgogos' answer is suited.

The goal is to compare execution time of several images to draw a conclusion about the different tools used.

Comment: Wall clock, or cpu time?

Comment: Speaking of wall clock (regular time)

Comment: You can just `time docker run ...` if the container does its thing and exits.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## 1st approach: `time`

```
time docker run --rm --name=test alpine ping -c 10 8.8.8.8
...

real    0m10.261s
user    0m0.228s
sys 0m0.044s
```

but this will also include the time for *creating* and *removing* the container.

## 2nd approach: container information

The information you are looking for is stored by docker and can be reached by `docker container inspect`.

```
docker run --name=test alpine ping -c 10 8.8.8.8
```

* notice that I didn't use `--rm` because the next step is to inpect the container. You will have to remove it afterwards. The timestamps you might be interested in are:

- `"Created": "2018-08-02T10:16:48.59705963Z",`
- `"StartedAt": "2018-08-02T10:16:49.187187456Z",`
- `"FinishedAt": "2018-08-02T10:16:58.27795818Z"`

---

```
$ docker container inspect test

[
    {
        "Id": "96e469fdb437814817ee2e9ad2fcdbf468a88694fcc998339edd424f9689f71f",
        "Created": "2018-08-02T10:16:48.59705963Z",
        "Path": "ping",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "10",
            "8.8.8.8"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-08-02T10:16:49.187187456Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2018-08-02T10:16:58.27795818Z"
        }
...
```

#### Duration calculation example (with bash):

You can put these timestamps in bash variables with single commands like this:

```
START=$(docker inspect --format='{{.State.StartedAt}}' test)
STOP=$(docker inspect --format='{{.State.FinishedAt}}' test)
```

Then you can convert them to UNIX epoch timestamps (**seconds** since Jan 01 1970. (UTC))

```
START_TIMESTAMP=$(date --date=$START +%s)
STOP_TIMESTAMP=$(date --date=$STOP +%s)
```

and if you subtract these two, you get the duration in seconds...

```
echo $(($STOP_TIMESTAMP-$START_TIMESTAMP)) seconds
9 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider a couple of things:

1. How to get time execution of a process given a PID.
2. Execute `docker exec` specifying PID=1 because container time running = entrypoint running.

Combining two things you get docker container time execution with:

```
docker exec -ti <container_id> ps -o etime= -p "1"
```

It gives you more accuracy than column **STATUS** of `docker ps` command.

If you're executing several processes in container and you need execution time for any of them, just replace "1" by its PID inside container.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach may be to override the default [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) with the `time` command.

```
$ docker run --rm --name=test --entrypoint=time alpine ping -c 10 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=37 time=51.213 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=37 time=7.844 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=37 time=8.120 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=37 time=10.859 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=4 ttl=37 time=10.975 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=5 ttl=37 time=12.520 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=6 ttl=37 time=7.994 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=7 ttl=37 time=8.904 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=8 ttl=37 time=6.674 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=9 ttl=37 time=7.132 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 6.674/13.223/51.213 ms
real    0m 9.02s
user    0m 0.00s
sys 0m 0.00s
```

Doing this won't include the container start up time. You can even do something like:
 `time docker run --rm --name=test --entrypoint=time alpine ping -c 10 8.8.8.8` to see how long just the container startup takes.