# How to get the runtime information of a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, podman

What is the way to figure out what is the container runtime? Is it Kube/docker/podman etc?
Earlier there were ways to figure out like reading the content of "/run/systemd/container" file or by getting the env variable "container".

Looks like there were some changes done to docker & podman. Now the above methods no longer are telling us what is the container runtime.

Is there a way to determine the container runtime during container initialization itself?

Comment: can you refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651386/19230181) by tgogos which helps you in getting runtime of a container.

Comment: Thank you. I think the above link is using docker command, but if we are checking on a podman,it wouldn't help.Looking for a generic command which would tell if the runtime is docker/podman/kube etc

Comment: Can you check this [How to use Podman to get information about your containers](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-information-podman) blog by Alexon Oliveira and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks again. But both the above methods tell you to use either podman/docker commands to determine, but i want a generic method to get the runtime info. The reason i was asking is i want to log the container runtime in my logs as my container can run on any of the runtimes. Hence there should be a generic way either reading some file or running some generic command to determine the runtime

Comment: if im not wrong you are looking for a command which would tell if the runtime is docker/podman/kube etc then Can use the `kubectl describe node <nodename>` command to get information about the container runtime used by the nodes in your cluster. Look for the "Container Runtime Version" field in the output. This [doc](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/how-to-check-which-runtime-a-node-is-using/7385) is the example and the same shown in [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/find-out-runtime-you-use/#find-out-the-container-runtime-used-on-a-node) also

Comment: That command will help only when you are running in kubernetes environment.But what about when you are running the container outside kubernetes

Comment: Have you any solution to this and seems to be there is no such generic command and can you raise a request in [Kubernetes Community](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/) might help you in enhancing this request.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command to see what is your container runtime
kubectl get nodes -o wide

for more information you can check this link
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/find-out-runtime-you-use/

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the `.HostConfig.Runtime` value inside the `docker inspect` output:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.Runtime }}' <container-name>
```

If you want to do it on every container you have, type the command:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.Runtime }}' $(sudo docker ps -aq)
```

Comment: But the above works if it is docker environment. If it is podman/kube how do we get.Is there a generic way to get the runtime information